# RecordRTC making noise without headphone video recording

Tags: javascript, audio, video, noise, recordrtc

I am new to RecordRTC.js, i have simple application that record audio and video and save that video. this is working fine if i record video using headphone. but if i remove the headphone and try to record video then it creating some terrible noise. some time happen like if i refresh the page then it not making the noise but if i plugged-in the headphone and remove it and press the record button then it start making the noise.

here is my code to start recording.

```
function captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
}

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    streamMedia = stream;
    var videoPreview = document.getElementById('webrtcVideo');
    var videoFile = !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'video.gif' : 'video.webm';

    videoPreview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    videoPreview.play();
    recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, {
        type: 'video'
    });
    recordVideo.startRecording();
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

/**
 * This function will be called from html on click of record button.
 */
function startRecording() {
    captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
}
```

[RecordRTC](http://recordrtc.org/)

Comment: Are you sure its `video.gif` ? `gif` file should be soundless

Comment: What are you sending in `mediaConstraints` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: {
        mandatory: {
          echoCancellation: false,
          googAutoGainControl: false,
          googNoiseSuppression: false,
          googHighpassFilter: false
    },
    optional: [{
          googAudioMirroring: false
    }]
  },
};
function captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, successCallback,errorCallback) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
  .then(successCallback)
  .catch(errorCallback);
}
```